# The quest for a solution to a certain integral.

Tags: calculus

While playing around with repeated integrals with my friend, I came across the following integral.
$$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln (1-x)}{1+s^2x^2} dx=\dfrac{\arctan s \ln(1+s^2)}{2s}-\sum_{n≧0} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} s^{2n}$$
I solved the above integral in the following way.
$$proof:$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln (1-x)}{1+s^2x^2} dx=\sum_{n≧0} (-1)^n s^{2n}\int_{0}^{1} x^{2n} \ln(1-x) dx$$
$$=\sum_{n≧0} \dfrac{(-1)^n s^{2n}}{2n+1} (\psi(1)-\psi(2n+2))$$
$$=\sum_{n≧0} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1} s^{2n}}{2n+1} H_{2n+1}$$
$$=-\sum_{n≧0} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} s^{2n}+\sum_{n>0} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n+1} H_{2n} s^{2n}$$
$$\arctan x \ln (1+x^2)=\left( \int_{0}^x \dfrac{1}{1+t^2} dx\right) \left( \int_{0}^x \dfrac{2s}{1+s^2} ds\right)$$
$$=\left( \int_{0<t<s<x}+\int_{0<s<t<x}\right) \dfrac{dt}{1+t^2} \dfrac{2s}{1+s^2}$$
$$=2 \sum_{m,n≧0} (-1)^{m+n} x^{2m+2n+3} \left( \dfrac{1}{2(n+1)(2m+2n+3)}+\dfrac{1}{(2m+1)(2m+2n+3)}\right)$$
$$=2 \sum_{m≧n>0} \dfrac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2m+1} x^{2m+1} \left( \dfrac{1}{2n}+\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\right)$$
$$=2 \sum_{m>0} \dfrac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2m+1} H_{2m} x^{2m+1}$$
$$\therefore \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\ln (1-x)}{1+s^2x^2} dx=\dfrac{\arctan s \ln(1+s^2)}{2s}-\sum_{n≧0} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} s^{2n}$$
However, the solution method above involves a considerable amount of computation and complexity. Also, given my own personality, I'm eager to explore other answers. Are there any other good approaches available?
I'm open to any solution method, regardless of its nature or the field it comes from.  Additionally, since I'm seeking new approaches, there's no need to consider difficulty levels or other factors.
By the way, in the above proof, $H_n$ represents harmonic numbers (distinct from harmonic series), and $\psi(x)$ represents the digamma function. Additionally, $\arctan$ denotes the inverse function of tangent. $s$ is a parameter, and $\ln$ denotes the natural logarithm.

The discovery of this integral is my friend.
The proof has been verified by experts.